# When (if ever) would you do this in PHP?

Tags: php

I've been going through the code of a Wordpress plugin and found the following:

`eval( '?>' . $foo . '<?php ' );`

I'm curious if there is some specific situation I'm unaware of that this would be the right way to output the `$foo` variable.  Is this just a case of the plugin author being wacky or is there something I should know?  I would have just used `echo`...

UPDATE:

Thanks for all the great feedback.  I'm face palming now that I didn't think of the template scenario.  Specifically, this happens in the WP Super Cache plugin.  I guess I'll have to have a closer look to see if it's necessary.  I thought Super Cache cached the html output by Wordpress after all the PHP had already been processed...

Comment: That line of code is going to give me nightmares O.o

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this instance, `$foo` is a string that (presumably) can contain in-lined PHP code. As such, to execute this PHP code, the string needs to be `eval`'ed.

That said, the use of [eval](http://www.php.net/eval) is generally frowned upon, apart from in a *very* narrow set of circumstances, as it can lead to the execution of malicious code. (i.e.: If there's any possibility that `$foo` is a user-provided string, then use of `eval` could lead to disastrous consequences.)

See the existing [When is eval evil in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php) question/answers for more information.

Comment: But it wouldn't be PHP code, would it? Because you're also `eval` ing those close and open tags. `$foo` would have to contain HTML or something, right? (But in a string, obviously.)

Comment: @sdleihssirhc: Bingo.  This is frequently used to execute template code that is either mostly PHP or is PHP that needs some variety of string-level manipulation to work.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc Adding the start and end tags is necessary unless the string is *just* PHP code, as opposed to a string that contains embedded PHP tags.

Comment: @webarto It's rarely, if ever *good*, but sometimes a more pleasant alternative to writing your own parser. That said, it should *only* ever be used in strictly controlled circumstances.

Comment: @middaparka, I haven't hit downvote... I use eval for parsing code from database (which I enter manually)... but using eval like the plugin author did is, I personally think, a hack... Not quite sure what he was trying to do, but I am 99% sure it could be done without eval. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

That's not outputting the variable. `$foo` most likely contains a template, with other `<?=$code();?>` snippets embbeded.

The closing and opening PHP marker are used in this eval to switch from inline code, back to HTML mode. This eval() more or less amounts to:

```
include("data:,$foo");  // treat $foo string as if it was include script
```

Comment: It just happens that the `include` method requires `allow_url_include` be enabled, whereas the eval method does not.  Depressing...

Comment: Yep. The other workaround would be to save it into a temporary file. (But I would consider *that* even worse-worse.)

Answer (score -1):

Let me repeat it again: c.r.a.p

> If eval() is the answer, you're almost
>   certainly asking the wrong question.
>
> Rasmus Lerdorf

Comment: FYI, notice I'm not doing this.  I found it in a plugin.

Comment: Come on, I liked 2112 under my username. Plugin author is wacky, and Endophage just use `echo`. @Endophage, never said you did, and you shouldn't.